# Java for each loop iterate boolean array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I have a boolean array

```
boolean[] test = {
    false,
    true,
    true,
    false,
    true
};
```

and I'm trying to flip (true to false, and false to true) the values with "for-each" statement like so:

```
for(boolean x : test) {
    x = !x;
}
```

But it's only changing the `x` variable in the local scope.

I'm new to Java and I want to ask how this could be done and if this is the right approach. I've searched a lot, but most of the examples are used to collect data from the array without modifying it.

Comment: Have you tried to put your variable in list ? and actually what do you actually want ??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, that's not the right approach. The enhanced for loop doesn't let you change the values of what you're iterating over. To invert the array, you'd want to use a regular for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
    test[i] = !test[i];
}
```

(Note that the enhanced for loop would let you make changes to the *objects* which any array elements referred to, if they were classes - but that's not the same thing as changing the value of the element itself.)

Comment: We are not allowed to change the value we are iterating over, but why is so? What could be the consequences if we were allowed to do so

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use a non-enhanced for loop if you want affect the values of test:

```
for (int i = 0; i < test.length; ++i) {
  test[i] = !test[i];
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't the element `test[0]` remain unchanged because of the pre-increment `++i` ?

Comment: No.  The increment expression is evaluated AFTER each execution of the loop.  So, the first execution of the loop i would be assigned the value 0.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the item in a for-each loop. Can you use a regular loop instead?

```
for (int i=0; i < test.length; i++)
{
    test[i] = !test[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't do that with a for each, as the for each reads the value of the array, and stores it in a local variable, as you said. You need to iterate the array and access the index directly. I won't post any code so you can find and think about it.

Answer (score 1):

No surprises that it does not work. You are manipulating a local variable after all and its not an object and not a reference. Use a normal for loop and modify corresponding position.

Answer (score 0):

The enhanced for loop is creating a new variable x and setting the value locally each time because boolean is a primitive and is therefore not passed by reference. For this, you will need to use the old for loop.